# Не отрабатывает ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html5-history-api

Подскажите, столкнулся с вот такой проблемой, надо сделать на сайте, чтобы менялись страницы на ajax, но при этом менялся и url страницы, при решении этой проблемы использую jQuery address:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/jquery.address-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var init = true,
        state = window.history.pushState !== undefined;

    // Handles response
    var handler = $(this).attr('href'); {
        var data = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        $.address.title(data.title);
    };

    $.address.state('/myprogect/').init(function (event) {

        // Initializes the plugin
        $('a').address();

    }).change(function (event) {

        var value = $.address.state().replace(/^\/$/, '') + event.value;

        // Selects the proper navigation link
        $('a').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('href') == value) {
                $(this).addClass('selected').focus();
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
        });
        if (state && init) {

            init = false;

        } else {

            // Loads and populates the page data
            $.ajax({
                url: handler,
                cache: false,
                complete: handler,
                url: value,
            });
        });
    }

    if (!state) {

        // Hides the page during initialization
        document.write('<style type="text/css"> body { display: none; } </style>');
    }
</script>

<h4 class="alert-heading">Photos</h4>
<a href="photo?id=<?php echo $myrow[id] ?>">No photos finde.Upload photo<a>
```

Проблема в том, что не происходит ajax, что делать? Что в коде не то, подскажите, пожалуйста. Можно ли как-нибудь решить проблему по-другому с ajax'ом и изменением адреса. Что-то похожее есть вконтакте при смене страниц. Подскажите, пожалуйста!!

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Что в коде не то, подскажите, пожалуйста

что по вашему делают эти строчки:

```
var handler = $(this/*this == window*/).attr('href'); { // явно лишние скобки
    var data = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    $.address.title(data.title);
}; // или вы просто что-то пропустили
```

и эти:

```
    $.ajax({
          url: handler,
          cache: false,
          complete: handler, // в качестве колбэка указана ссылка
          url: value, // повторно указан url, лишняя запятая 
    });
}); // а это что за скобки? откуда они?
```

А где `domReady`?

Вы явно с трудом понимаете, что делаете (поправьте меня, если я не прав). Может стоило начать с более приземлённых вещей?

Answer (score 0):

complete: handler   -> success:function(response){ ... }  И будем вам счастье.  [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)